# Перемножить каждый элемент двумерного массива с каждым своим элементом на Java

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, перебор

Элементы массива int. Результат умножения просто вывести на экран. Cкорость роли не играет. Пробовал сам с вложенными циклами, запутался. Поиск в интернете не помог; нашёл только решение на языке программирования python, но это не то.
Моя попытка:

```
int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(arr[i][k] * arr[i][j]);
                if (k == 2)
                    k = 0;
                k++;
            }
```

Моя вторая попытка(тоже не очень, но мне подходит):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
                    for (int l = 0; l < arr[0].length; l++)
                        System.out.print(arr[i][j] * arr[k][l]);
```

Если есть у кого-нибудь ещё идеи - пишите.

Comment: Выкладывай свой код, что пробовал, что не получилось, какие проблемы возникли, что ожидал и что в итоге выводит

Comment: И что такое "каждый свой элемент"?

Comment: @MBo каждый элемент arr с каждым элементом массива arr

Comment: Пример покажите для небольшого массива

Comment: @MBo всмысле как выглядит в коде двумерный массив?

Comment: Нет, как получить результат, и чему он будет равен, например, для массива `[[2,3], [5,7]]`

Comment: @MBo Из вашего примера : 2*3 2*5 2*7 , а потом 3*2 3*5 3*7,; массив у меня 4 строки и 3 столбца

Comment: А что потом делать с этими числами (6, 10, 14...)? Их для вашего массива будет 132

Comment: @MBo их надо потом другому методу передать, я написал "вывод умножения" для упрощения понимания моего вопроса.

Comment: Во втором коде, видимо, надо добавить проверку, что оба индекса одновременно не совпадают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере число на себя не умножалось, поэтому исключим случай, когда оба индекса совпадают

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
                    for (int l = 0; l < arr[0].length; l++)
                        if (i!=k || j!=l) 
                            System.out.print(arr[i][j] * arr[k][l]);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: мой "косяк", испрвил.